# DoubleClick Studio, child not working on another server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to run a parent child banner created with DoubleClick studios.

It works fine on my computer but when I try to host the child on another server I get this message:

ProxyEnabler: The parent Enabler could not be found.

note I am using a polite loader.

pls help meh :)

Answer (score 0):

The proxy enabler is in the parent.  If you are only hosting the child it won't run.

You could try adding this to the child to make it run stand-alone:

```
import com.google.ads.studio.HtmlEnabler;
var enabler:Object;
enabler = HtmlEnabler.getInstance();
enabler.init( this );
```